# Laravel 8 Delete function does not throw error but isn't working

Tags: laravel, database, backend

When I press the delete button it redirects me successfully but does not delete the query in the database, my code is as follows:
Route:

```
Route::resource('v_users', VUserController::class);
```

Controller:

```
  public function destroy(request $request)
     {  
        
        v_users::destroy($request->id);
            session()->flash('delete');   
            return redirect()->route('v_users.index')
                        ->with('success','User deleted successfully');
    }
```

View.index:

```
 <form action="{{ route('v_users.destroy',$v_users->id) }}" method="POST">
   
                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('v_users.show',$v_users->id) }}">View QR Code</a>
                    <br>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('v_users.edit',$v_users->id) }}">Edit</a>
                    <br>
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
      
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </form>
```

Comment: What is `v_users`? A model?

Comment: In your form I do not see any input called `id`, therefore the `id` property does not exist in `$request` variable. Maybe you are trying to do a failed [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding).

Comment: @MrEduar v_users is the name of the model and I believe I am attempting to do a route model binding would you mind clarifying where my mistake is, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When injecting a model ID to a route or controller action, you will often query the database to retrieve the model that corresponds to that ID. So, in your route file you must make a declared parameter like `Route::get('/users/{v_user}', [UserController::class, 'delete'])`

Then, in your destroy method you must add the model that you are injecting

```php
public function destroy(Request $request, v_user $user)
{  

    $user->delete();
    session()->flash('delete');   

    return redirect()
            ->route('v_users.index')
            ->with('success','User deleted successfully');
}
```

Comment: In the case of using resource in my route would I need to change my method, or simply just add another route? I am new to developing in general, thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: Change your method only, as Laravel takes care of generating the route correctly, just make sure that the route name is the same as the variable.  That is, if you used `Route::resource('v_user', UserController::class);` then the parameter should be `$v_user`.

Answer (score 1):

Route

```
Route::resource('v_users', VUserController::class);
```

controller

```
public function destroy(VUsers $v_users)
{  
    VUsers->delete();
    session()->flash('delete');   
    return redirect()->route('v_users.index')
           ->with('success','User deleted successfully');
}
```

blade

```
<form action="{{ route('v_users.destroy',$v_users->id) }}" method="POST">
   
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```